# Stop magicsuggest from pre-loading dynamic source

Tags: jquery, magicsuggest

I am using the plugin from MaggicSuggest from:

nicolasbize.com

I have set it to delay @ 400ms , and minimum 3 chars required before it loads data.

I noticed that this plugin preloads data once during initiation.

What i wanted it to do is to not preload, but rather wait for user input.

Can this be done? Am i missing something?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I did this by

```
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            // return false if blank search string
            if(settings.url.indexOf('query=&') !== -1)
                return false;
        }
```

Comment: use beforeSend to stop the request if the query string is blank.